# Not able to display the output in google chrome

Tags: html, css

I was just trying to show some css effect.If a mouse moves into menu,then the submenu has to be slide down  from top to bottom.It was working in FIREFOX but in the CHROME  it was going from bottom to top.below is the HTML file.

```
 <head>

    <link media="all" href="alshop_menu_box.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link media="all" href="alshop_menu_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link media="all" href="alshop_menu_styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body class=" cms-index-index shadow lte-ie8 cms-home">
    <div class="nav-container itemgrid itemgrid-6cols"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle-product">
    <div class="gd-col navUnitContainer gu4 required-tracking" data-tracking-id="vn_clothing">
    <div class="title">Games</div>
    <div class="content">
    <img width="212px" height="230px" data-src="#" alt="" src="images/java3.jpg"><!--product image-->
    </div>
    <div class="links">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a class="active" href="#">GTA</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">WWE</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">fifa 14</a>
    </li>
    <li>
    <a href="#">fifa13</a>
    </li>
    <li class="view-all">
    <a class="view-all-link" data-tracking-id="1" href="#">View All »</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And my three css files
alshop_menu_boc.css

```
.gu4 {
    width: 234px;
}
.navUnitContainer .title {
    background: url("java3.png") no-repeat scroll right 13px #4B4B4B;
    bottom: 1px;
    color: #FF96ff;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: px;
    font-weight: bold;
    left: 1px;
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 221px;
    z-index: 2;
}
/*************************************CHANGE TO SLIDE UP**********************************
.navUnitContainer .content {
    font-size: 0;
    height: 216px;
    line-height: 0; 
}*/
.navUnitContainer .content img {
    border: 1px solid #DEDEDE;
    height: 212px;
    left: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    width: 230px;
}
.navUnitContainer {
    margin-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
}
.navUnitContainer .links {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    bottom: 0;
    height: 147px;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 2px 2px 1px;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear 0s;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.navUnitContainer .links a {
    color: #FF96ff;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.navUnitContainer .links a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.navUnitContainer .links .view-all {
    bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
.navUnitContainer .links .view-all a {
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
.navUnitContainer .links .view-all a:hover {
    background-color: #FF96ff;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navUnitContainer:hover .links {
    opacity: 1;
    transition-delay: 0s;/*************************************DELAY IN SLIDE DOWN******************************/
    visibility: visible;
}
.navUnitContainer:hover .links .view-all {
    opacity: 1;
}
.navUnitContainer:hover .title {
    background-color: #FF96ff;
    color:#FFFFFF
}
.navUnitContainer:hover .content img {
    border: 1px solid #FF96ff;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.browser-warn {
    padding: 10px;
}
.browser-warn .logo {
    background: url("../prod/images/browsers-d9f97dca.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    display: block;
    height: 72px;
    width: 52px;
}
.browser-warn .IE {
    background-position: -51px 0;
}
.browser-warn .Firefox {
    background-position: -107px 0;
}
.browser-warn .Safari {
    background-position: -161px 0;
}
.browser-warn .Chrome {
    background-position: 1px 45px;
}
```

alshop_menu_style.css

```
@charset "utf-8";
.middle-product .links ul li {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.middle-product .links ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #FF96ff !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
.middle-product {
    float: center;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 738px;
}

.navUnitContainer {
    margin: 0 8px 10px;
    width: 231px !important;
}
```

alshop_menu_styles.css

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}
body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333333;
    font: 75%/150% Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    border: 0 none;
    max-width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
}
a {
    color: #888888;
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
    color: #CA0413;
    text-decoration: none;
}
:focus {
    outline: 0 none;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 1.75em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.25em;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.6666em;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 1.1666em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h5 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h6 {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form {
    display: inline;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0 none;
}
legend {
    display: none;
}
table {
    border: 0 none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    empty-cells: show;
    font-size: 100%;
}
caption, th, td {
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
strong {
    font-weight: bold;
}
address {
    font-style: normal;
}
cite {
    font-style: normal;
}
q, blockquote {
    quotes: none;
}
q:before, q:after {
    content: "";
}
small, big {
    font-size: 1em;
}
sup {
    font-size: 1em;
    vertical-align: top;
}
ul, ol {
    list-style: none outside none;
}
.col-main {
    float: left;
}
.links li a, #mini-cart .block-title, .header .block-compare .block-title {
    line-height: 2.6666em;
    padding: 0 0.5833em;
}
.links li {
    float: left;
}
.links a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Have you validated it? I guess not. Do it! Oh and don't post your full code here, make a small example of your problem.

Comment: @Layne how to validate?Can you tell me?

Comment: [w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/). as Layne said, posting all your code here wont help. if anything create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML code was not well formed.
The Doctype was missing as well as some other minor errors. Try this one out.

In the CSS, float cannot be 'center'. It's either 'right' or 'left'.

Finally, also in your css, 'font-size' has a value of px. You should have a valid value eg '13px'.

```
<head>
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    <link media="all" href="alshop_menu_box.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link media="all" href="alshop_menu_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link media="all" href="alshop_menu_styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class=" cms-index-index shadow lte-ie8 cms-home">
    <div class="nav-container itemgrid itemgrid-6cols"></div>
    <div class="middle-product">
        <div class="gd-col navUnitContainer gu4 required-tracking" data-tracking-id="vn_clothing">
            <div class="title">Games</div>
            <div class="content">
                <img width="212" height="230" data-src="#" alt="" src="images/java3.jpg">
                <!--product image-->
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <ul>
                    <li> <a class="active" href="#">GTA</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">WWE</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">fifa 14</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href="#">fifa13</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="view-all"> <a class="view-all-link" data-tracking-id="1" href="#">View All »</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```